# About MethodInfo Invoke exception

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

I have one C# clause "DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)"

Now I want to analysis that clause and invoke that AddDays method by reflection as below：

```
var parameters = new List<object>();
            if (mce.Arguments.Any())
            {
                parameters = mce.Arguments.Select(arg => Convert.ChangeType(DealExpress(arg, false), arg.Type)).ToList();
            }
            var res = mce.Method.Invoke(mce.Object, parameters.ToArray());
```

But I got an exception about "Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The object does not match the target type。"

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we could copy and paste into a console app and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I get the reason, bcuz this mce.Object is an Expression